# Switching between storyboard localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, storyboard

I have application using storyboard with two language (Ar/En) how i can switch from Arabic storyboard to English storyboard without need to change language iPhone settings (At run time).

When user change manually the language, i use :

```
+ (void)setDefaultLocalizationLanguage:(NSString *)language{
  [UserPreferences setDefaultLanguage:language];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:language, nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

In AppDelegate, I add method switchTolanguage:

```
-(void)switchTolanguage:(NSString *)lang{
   NSBundle *bnd = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:lang ofType:@"lproj" ]];
   UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:bnd];
   UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
   self.window.rootViewController = initViewController;
}
```

I execute the last method in my ViewController :

```
AppDelegate *appdelagate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appdelagate switchTolanguage:[UserPreferences defaultLanguage]];
```

But I have the same storyboard localization with this logs:

```
Could not load the "4_icon_4.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "(null)"
Could not load the "1_logo.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "(null)"
Could not load the "1_bacground_img.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "(null)"
```

But when I kill application and I open it, I have the good storyboard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259674/switching-between-localized-storyboard-at-runtime was almost the same question, maybe it'll help you.

Comment: thank you @MichaëlAzevedo , i have update my question, i added more details.

Comment: What are the possible values for `lang`  parameter in `switchTolanguage` ? If you use `En` as in your question it won't work since the lproj folder is named `en`

Comment: I use "en" and "ar-001", I check that I have two folders en.lproj and ar-001.lproj